# how do i display records row by row at JList

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jlist, defaultlistmodel

As I have returned a ListModel from another class 'Food', the following code results in displaying just a single row of records from the DB. How may i populate my records at the JList row by row?

I believe I will have to alter my existing code, but how?

```
   Food food = new Food();
   JList list = new JList();
   list.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
   list.setBounds(20, 89, 220, 217);
   contentPane.add(list);

   DefaultListModel DLM = new DefaultListModel();
   DLM.addElement(food.populateJList());
   list.setModel(DLM);
```

Comment: How is the .populateJList() method of Food class?

Comment: I think I've just solved it, sorry & thanks anyw :)